# Implementing ASP.NET CORE Tag Helper to Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I trying to implement tag helper inside javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addJsonContentField").click(function () {


        var fType = this.innerHTML(@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.templateDDLType, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(templateDDL)))) );

        fieldWrapper.append(fType);
```

However, i keep getting error which the html cannot support because of the line break.
[Error Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmXtP.png) What could be the reason for this issues?

Comment: You'll also need to wrap it in quotes. `innerHTML` expects a string.

Comment: the line still break even though i quote the string

Comment: Wrap it in *single* quotes, not double. However, I'd imagine this isn't actually what you're truly looking for, and are likely expecting this to be somewhat dynamic. That's not the case. The dropdown HTML string will be rendered server-side, while this JS will not run until later, after the server has sent the response to the client.

Comment: @ChrisPratt anything for me to reference please?

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
  var selectList = document.createElement("select");
  selectList.className = "fieldtype";

        @string.Format("var fType = {{{0}}}; ", string.Join(",", Enum.GetNames(typeof(templateDDL)).ToList().ConvertAll(key => { return string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, (int)((templateDDL)Enum.Parse(typeof(templateDDL), key))); }).ToArray()))

        $.each(fType, function (i, items) { 
            var option = new Option(i, items);
            selectList.appendChild(option);

        });
```